# How to access the main Camera in Unity to make a zoom script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple zoom script for when you click on a cube. I want it to zoom in on the cube, but I cannot find a way to make the main camera zoom for me. I have tried several different ways. Here is the current one. I had it in a `OnMouseDown`, but it still would not work, so I moved it to update to see if I could get it to work.

```
void Update ()
{
  if(Input.GetKeyDown("z"))
  {
    Debug.Log("Pressed Z");
    zoomedIn = !zoomedIn;
  }

  if(zoomedIn == true)
  {
      Debug.Log("True!");
      Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, zoom, Time.deltaTime*smooth);
  }
  else
  {
     Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, normal, Time.deltaTime*smooth);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: you should not `GetComponent<Camera>()` after accesing `Camera.main`: it is already `Camera` type. And second - does it work now when you moved it to `Update`?

Comment: Use `GetKeyUp` instead of `GetKeyDown`, because `GetKeyDown` may potentially return `true` multiple times over multiple frames, but `GetKeyUp` returns `true` only in one frame.

Comment: No, it does not work when I moved it to Update.

Comment: It prints out the Debug statements but does not zoom the camera at all.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You want to continue zooming in when z is held down? You want to zoom in by ...percent when z is pressed?When do you want to zoom out? No one knows what you  are trying to do

Comment: I want to zoom in when when a specific gameobject, in this case, a cube, is clicked on. I want it to zoom in on the cube.

Comment: Ok. How is the Camera positioned in front of the Cube? Camera  is in front of Cube in axis, Y or X axis...

Comment: The Camera is at (10,0,6) the cube is at (3.93,-1.44,7).

Comment: Why not put a simple screen shot of the cam and cube pos.

Comment: Here is the link to the screen shot: http://imgur.com/a/Wg6F5

Comment: No.  Select the camera and the cube, then press F to zoom in on both of them. Take a screenshot of the sceneview not gameview or the hierarchy.

Comment: Here: http://imgur.com/a/cBYBO

Comment: questions like this are a ridiculous chaotic time waste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `zoom` and `normal` are not assigned to the correct values. Also make sure that you're in `Perspective`, not `Orthographic` view.

> If you want to use `Orthographic` view just change all usages of `fieldOfView` to [`orthographicSize`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html) and change `zoom` to something reasonable, like 5 units.

`normal` should be the initial `fieldOfView` of the camera, retrieved in `Start`:

```
// camera is a private field
private Camera camera;
camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
normal = camera.fieldOfView;
```

`zoom` should be a value *less* than `normal` (initial `fieldOfView`) assigned from the inspector to be able to "zoom in".

Your conditional branch will change to

```
if (zoomedIn) // Same as if (zoomedIn == true)
{
    camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(camera.fieldOfView, zoom, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
else
{
    camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(camera.fieldOfView, normal, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
```

Or, a more concise version:

```
camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(camera.fieldOfView, zoomedIn ? zoom : normal, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
```

I also suggest using a Coroutine to do this instead of doing this in `Update`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out now!

Comment: GetComponent<Camera> seems to not be working for me. I get error CS0120: An ojbect reference is required to access non-static member 'UnityEngine.Camera.fieldOfView'

Comment: @SamCurry you're probably using `Camera` instead of the private field `camera`. Note the lower case "c"! Make sure that you use `camera.fieldOfView` and not `Camera.fieldOfView` everywhere.

Comment: You're right! Now I get the problem that it cannot convert a float to an int on line 16. (Sorry, I am still learning)

Comment: @SamCurry you've probably made `normal` an `int`. Change `int` to `float` where you've defined `normal`.